# Try to get informations with Simple Html Dom Parser

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I need your help! I'm banging my head against a brick wall since two days without success.
I'm new with PHP (I started several months ago).

I use the class **Simple HTML Dom Parser** to get some information's from a web page:

1°) a number after "library-". *Example*: 199459

couple with a series of links:

2°) "/index.php/link-to-get-878220"

I try to get those information's in tab, that way:

```
    Array
    (
    [Movies] => Array
    (
    [199459] => /index.php/link-to-get-878219
    [199459] => /index.php/link-to-get-878220
    [198210] => /index.php/link-to-get-878452
    [198210] => /index.php/link-to-get-878453
    [198210] => /index.php/link-to-get-878454
    [198210] => /index.php/link-to-get-878455
    )
    )
```

As you can see, each number (ie:198210) is the key of several values (all the values contained in the div with id="library-??????" have the same key)

Problem:

- I got some waste (ie: movies_1) when I try to get the number.
- I do not succeed to parallel numbers and links in the array (that's why I didn't added an example in the code)

English is not my native language so do not hesitate to ask insights on some words I used!

**my code:**

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');$movies = array();
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file("pt.html");

foreach($html->find('div.libraries div[id*=library-]') as $library):
$movies['idMovie'][] = str_replace('library-', '', $library->id);
foreach($html->find('.list-movies tr') as $links):
$movies['links'][] = $links->find('.nom a',0)->href;
endforeach;
endforeach;
```

**And the HTML I try to get information's from:**

```
<div class="libraries library_movie-tabs red tabs">
<div class="libraries library_element-tabs red tabs">
<div id="library-199459" class="tabs-content">
<div class="inner">
<p class="info"><strong>Library 1:</strong>Fantasy Movies</p>
</div>

<div class="inner">
<table width="100%" class="library-table list-movies">
<tr>
<td width="40"></td>

<td width="228" class="nom"><a title="Conan"
href= "/index.php/link-to-get-878219"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="40"></td>

<td width="228" class="nom"><a title="Lord-Of-The-Ring" 
href= "/index.php/link-to-get-878220"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="library-movies_1" class="library-movies">
...
</div> 
</div>

<div id="library-198210" class="tabs-content">
<div class="inner">
<p class="info"><strong>Library 2 :</strong>S-F Movies</p>
</div>

<div class="inner">
<table width="100%" class="library-table list-movies">
<tr>
<td width="40"></td>

<td width="228" class="nom"><a title="Tron" 
href= "/index.php/link-to-get-878452"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="40"></td>

<td width="228" class="nom"><a title="Starwars" 
href= "/index.php/link-to-get-878453"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="40"></td>

<td width="228" class="nom"><a title="Star-Trek" 
href= "/index.php/link-to-get-878454"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="40"></td>

<td width="228" class="nom"><a title="Predator" 
href= "/index.php/link-to-get-878455"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="library-movies_1" class="library-movies">
...
</div> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in the inner `foreach` you want to iterate `$library`, mot `$html`

```
foreach($html->find('.tabs-content') as $library){
  $item = array('links' => array());
  $key = str_replace('library-', '', $library->id);
  foreach($library->find('a') as $a){
    $item['links'][] = $a->href;
  }
  $movies[$key] = $item;
}
```